# Skeleton Boilerplate Loading Very Slow

Tags: performance, load, boilerplate

Im trying to use Skeleton Boilerplate. I downloaded the basic zip, comes with images folder only holding a favicon, `normalize.css`, `skeleton.css`, and a very basic `index.html`. When I try styling the index with my own linked css, just a basic thing like a background color on the single div, or changing the text or title, it takes FOREVER to refresh the page. Its supposed to be super lightweight and looks to be, idk whats going on

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'Font' link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" from index.html Skeleton and it should work at correct speed. It was what was slowing it down on my comp. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to add the "https:" to the link.
Thats it!

Comment: It seems to be a network latency issue for css/js used from CDN. All CDNs are supposed to be https. Http or https doesn't make a huge difference in network latency.

Comment: You are completly right, but in the index.html file from skeleton it looks like this 

<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

Loading **jQuery** remotely is probably why you are having loading issues. In particular, if you download jQuery and replace `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside `index.html` to point to your locally downloaded version of jQuery, things should be as fast as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Thinnling said, you should remove or edit the Google Font link.

index.html:

Old:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

New:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
```

skeleton.css:

(line 123)

```
body{ font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }
```